# GTK# (GTK Sharp 2.12) Radiobutton Font

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I keep running into this issue, but I typically ignore it if it's not critical.  I finally need to *genuinely resolve* this issue now instead of ignoring or working around it.  Basically it's this...

I am unable to find a method for changing the font of a CheckButton or a RadioButton.  The issue might also exist for a ToggleButton since both of the previous two are underneath it in the hierarchy (http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/widgets/widget-hierarchy/) and I can't also change the font of the parent Button widget.

The typical method to change the font of a widget is to use the ModifyFont(...) method, but obviously that's not working in this case.

Does anyone have a **working** example of code that resolves this?  I'm at a loss and I'd prefer not to write a custom widget.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### EDIT

I figured it out. Button's apparently don't have any text, but instead the text of any button is a child Label widget. `radiobutton1.Child.ModifyFont (Pango.FontDescription.FromString ("Comic Sans MS 10"))` changed the font of the radio button.

#### Previous Answer

I found a crude hack that changes the font for every widget drawn: `button1.Settings.FontName = "Comic Sans MS 10"`. **Settings** is a global property and overrides the RC file information. That's probably not much help though.

I tried a few other ways of changing the font with no success.

`button1.PangoContext.FontDescription = Pango.FontDescription.FromString ("Comic Sans MS 10");`

`button1.ModifierStyle.FontDesc = Pango.FontDescription.FromString ("Comic Sans MS 10");`

```
RcStyle style = new RcStyle ();
style.FontDesc = Pango.FontDescription.FromString ("Comic Sans MS 10");
button1.ModifyStyle (style);
```

Comment: .Child.ModifyFont(..) does indeed work.  Thank you.  I had tried the other methods as well, but it never occurred to me to try this method.  Excellent!

Question, any idea how to also change a Treeview's column header font?

Comment: No, sorry. I don't have any experience with TreeView's.

Comment: I figured it out, as well as, how to change a regular Button's font.  I've pasted them as a separate answer so they'll stand out if anyone else needs those answers.

Comment: I am also using Gtk# 2.12, however I'm able to change the font of a regular button the same as a RadioButton.

Comment: For some reason I was not.  It required me to go with this convulated method that I pasted below.  I'm not real sure what's up with that.

Answer (score 0):

Skyler Brandt successfully answered my initial question, so all credit goes to him for that one!  I was also faced with two other issues that I found the answers for and wanted to post the solutions here in case anyone else ever needs them.

(Original Issue Solved, Thanks Skyler)
**Change RadioButton/CheckButton/ToggleButton font.**

```
radioButton1.Child.ModifyFont(FontDescription.FromString("whatever"));
```

(New Issue #1, Solved)
**Change Treeview column header font.**

```
TreeViewColumn column1 = new TreeViewColumn();
Label label1 = new Label("My Awesome Label");
label1.ModifyFont(FontDescription.FromString("whatever"));
label1.Show();
column1.Widget = label1;
```

(New Issue #2, Solved)
**Change regular Button font.**
This one gets a bit hairy because the button's label is a great-grand child widget in the hierarchy.  The easiest thing to do was to create an extension method for Gtk.Button for easy usage.  If anyone has a better method please let me know.  (Skylar notes that he is able to change a regular button's font using the same method as a radiobutton; however, I'm not able to.  I'm not sure what's up with that.)

```
public static void ModifyLabelFont(this Gtk.Button button, string fontDescription)
{
    foreach(Widget child in button.AllChildren)
    {
        if(child.GetType() != (typeof(Gtk.Alignment)))
            continue;

        foreach(Widget grandChild in ((Gtk.Alignment)child).AllChildren)
        {
            if(grandChild.GetType() != (typeof(Gtk.HBox)))
                continue;

            foreach(Widget greatGrandChild in ((Gtk.HBox)grandChild).AllChildren)
            {
                if(greatGrandChild.GetType() != (typeof(Gtk.Label)))
                    continue;

                string text = ((Gtk.Label)greatGrandChild).Text;

                ((Gtk.HBox)grandChild).Remove(greatGrandChild);

                Label label = new Label(text);
                label.ModifyFont(FontDescription.FromString(fontDescription));
                label.Show();

                ((Gtk.HBox)grandChild).Add(label);
            }
        }                    
    }
}
```